# Code Cleaning Etiquette

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I understand and support the rules and etiquette for asking questions. The guidelines have increased the efficiency and quality of my own problem solving. However I have not found much on the subject or approach of code cleaning and review.

On occasion I research and write some code to solve a unique problem. Although my finished product works, I am sure that it is not efficient. Is there etiquette, rules or a way to post research and code specifically for community review?

Comment: I think that depend on which site you want to post that...and then this question is maybe better asked on that meta instead of here....or I miss the point of your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) specifically for working code that you want peer reviewed. Check the [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) for the site before posting to make sure your question/code fits.